# missing js if no user is logged in (drupal)

Tags: php, drupal

I'm using a fresh Drupal install. In my page.tpl.php file, I have the standard:

```
<?php print $head; ?> 
<?php print $styles; ?>
<?php print $scripts; ?>
```

And this works fine, most of the time. But when there is no user logged in, the scripts don't print, and no js is included in the page at all.

Is there a configuration option that I'm missing, or is this intended behavior, or what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could look at this - http://drupal.org/node/802432.

Create an empty script.js file in the theme directory and reload the theme (go to admin/build/themes, reselect your theme & hit submit). It did work for me.

Answer (score 0):

See http://drupal.org/node/802432.  Some other users have reported similar occurrences

A few users in that thread replied that adding a blank javascript file called *script.js* into their theme folder and clearing the cache resolved their problems of javascript not loading while logged out.